# ¿Cómo activar un onclick al cargar la página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que se active un `onclick` al momento de que cargue la página

```
<a href='cargar' onclick='myFunction'>cargar automaticamente</a>
```

tengo este codigo JavaScript pero no me funcionó:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // despues del código
  $('.cargar').click();
});
</script>
```

**¿cómo hago?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema en tu codigo es que estas llamando el selector de una clase `$(".cargar").click()` mientras en el html tu link es `<a href='cargar' onclick='myFunction'>cargar automaticamente</a>` osea que no tiene clase.

para hacer la carga automatica y simular el click de usuario con `.click()` en este caso el enclance o tag `<a></a>` no es lo adecuado.

el atributo `href` sirve para redireccionar la pagina, osea cambiar el url. lo que tendrias que hacer para que funcione es lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".cargar").click();
});
function myFunction(){

   console.log("cargando");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="cargar" type="button" onclick='myFunction()'>cargar automaticamente </button>
```

cambiar el enclance por un boton ya que lo que estas intentando hacer es cargar datos a traves de una funcion pasada por onclick y no redirigir a otra pagina.

a este boton le agregas la clase `cargar` asi tu `$(".cargar").click()` punta a ese boton gracias a el selector.

**PD: Recuerda que el selector `.` llama el atributo `class` mientras el selector `#` llama el atributo `id`, te recomiendo que mires este [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) en ingles para entender los selectores css, que son los mismos utilizados en jQuery**

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos

Answer (score 3):

Tienes 2 opciones

1. `$(document).ready()` ejecutará código hasta que todo el DOM quede listo
2. `$(window).on("load", function(){})` que ejecutará el código hasta que la página completa este lista, eso incluye iframes, imágenes, etc

Entonces una manera de asegurar que un evento `click` asociado a un botón se ejecute hasta que la página este lista puede quedar de este modo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="carga">Clic me</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      let button = $("#carga")
      
      $(window).on("load", function(){
        button.click(function(){
          console.log("hola Mundo")
        })
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Donde como puedes notar

1. Accedemos por medio de JQuery al objeto `Window` y posterior a eso con ayuda de `load` verificamos que absolutamente todo de la página web este cargado
2. Ejecutamos una función anónima como segundo argumento y por dentro de esta función anónima colocamos todo el código que debe funcionar hasta después de haber cargado la página web en su totalidad

Acceso a la documentación para referenciar [jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Aunque es claro que con `addEventListeners` en JS puro lo podríamos lograr igual, aquí un ejemplo

```
let button = document.getElementById("carga")

  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      console.log("Hola Mundo")
    })
  })
```

Comment: quien vota negativo sería bueno que argumente el por que

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente cuando capturas un evento click para ejecutar alguna función lo haces con el evento onclick, pero para ejecutar el mismo código(usando jquery como al parecer quieres usar) cuando la página esté cargada:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    //Aquí va tu código... 
})
```

Con eso bastaría... Solo pones las instrucciones que quieres hacer con el click dentro de esta función

Answer (score 2):

Deberias de añadir parentesis al codigo:

`<a href='cargar' onclick='myFunction()'>cargar automaticamente</a>`

Pero, creo que deberías de llamar a la función directamente sin forzar el click a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario. Esto hará el código mas legible

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   myFunction();
});
```